# Python_d.exe and venv -- can't find "python_d.exe"

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, virtualenv, python-venv

I'm using PyCharm and trying to set up a Flask project with a virtual environment. Whenever I select to do "New environment using Virtualenv" the base interpreter location seems to be right yet I continually get the error that there is no such file or directory "\python_d.exe" I don't think this is just a PyCharm error as I also get the same error when trying to do it from the terminal. I'm not quite sure why it's looking for python_d.exe instead of python.exe

I've already edited my PATH variable to be where my python executable is stored. And while installing Python (at the recommendation of other questions on this forum), selected to add to the PATH variable and also install for all users. I'm not sure where else to go on this, so any help is appreciated.

This is the error I get when I run the below command on the terminal.

```
> python -m venv C:\<path to where I want it to go>\venv
Error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\<my specific path>\Python\\Python37-32\\lib\\venv\\scripts\\nt\\python_d.exe'
```

Answer (score 1):

In the installation program of python seek if you have installed the debug file binaries.

python_d.exe is a file installed with that option activated.